# How to append JSON date into JKCalendar using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am using `JKCalendar` with some customization for my application requirement. Here, I need to load `JSON date` into `calendar` for underline mark. How to achieve this?

**JKCalendar**

https://github.com/JoeCiou/JKCalendar

**My JSON**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "count": 7,
            "start_date": "2019-09-11"
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "start_date": "2019-09-12"
        }
     ]
}
```

**JSON Codable**

```
struct Event: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [EvaDat]
}

struct EvaDat: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let startDate: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count
        case startDate = "start_date"
    }
}
```

**JSON Decoder Code**

```
var eventCount = [EvaDat]()  // Storing array for loading date into calendar  mark

 do {
           let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Event.self,  from: data)
           let status = decoder.status
             if status == true {
                     self.eventCount = decoder.data
                 }
  } catch {
         print(error) }
```

**Calendar Date Appending**

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JKCalendar, marksWith month: JKMonth) -> [JKCalendarMark]? {

        let firstMarkDay: JKDay = JKDay(year: 2019, month: 9, day: 20)! // How to append my array date

        var marks: [JKCalendarMark] = []
        if firstMarkDay == month{
            marks.append(JKCalendarMark(type: .underline,
                                        day: firstMarkDay,
                                        color: markColor))
        }
        return marks
    }
```

Comment: @vadian could you please help on this?

Comment: @RajeshKumar R could you please help me on this. Do you have any idea about this problem?